# Corrupted Image error when sharing a page in Facebook that has a og:image with url frin Google firebase storage

Tags: firebase, facebook-opengraph

When sharing an url of my site that has og:image with a url of a image stored in google storage (uploaded using firebase), Facebook is not showing the image, and in the Sharing Debugger, an error is being reported for the image:

> Provided og:image URL,
> https://storage.googleapis.com/vambuu-997b6.appspot.com/public/0Jf15FxlxzNcPdkAIaire3CiCxJ3/images/5uT0IZR9iO.jpg
> could not be processed as an image. It may be corrupted or may have an
> invalid format.

The strange thing is that this was working fine in the past 3 months, but suddenly stopped working.

And this error occurs only on Facebook, all other social shares, such as Linkedin, Twitter and Whatsapp the image is being shown. Also, if opening the url in a browser tab, it is being loaded with no problems.

The image was uploaded with firebase (using AngularFire) and on the server side (inside a function) I'm calling the file.makePublic() method and building the url with the pattern: https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME

Does it require additional operation to make the image readable by Facebook shares?

[image]

Comment: I got the same issue! I thought it had to do with my images being uploaded as base64 maybe, but yours is a jpg...